# Angular2 Headers not setting up properly

Tags: angular, http-headers

I'm making a simple post request using angular2 http.

The problem is it doesn't set header properly. Instead of setting content type and authorization, all I get is this

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:api.joinmunch.com
Origin:http://localhost:8100
Referer:http://localhost:8100/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
```

Here is my code

```
    let bodyString = JSON.stringify(user); // Stringify payload
    let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
    headers.append('Authorization', 'bearer MY_AUTH_TOKEN');

    let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option
    options.withCredentials = true;

    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'customer/register', bodyString, { headers: headers }) // ...using post request
                         .map((res:Response) => res.json()) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); //...errors if an
```

Here is the response headers

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 14 Oct 2016 16:03:36 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
```

[image: screen shot of request and response]

Answer (score 0):

That's just the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) preflight request, not the actual request. You can tell that the headers would be set on the real request from this

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization, content-type
```

The preflight request is asking the server if it will accept the `content-type` and `authorization` headers, which are the headers that you set

If you don't know about CORS, then check out the link. Maybe it will help you solve any *real* problem you may have, because the problem is not with the headers not being set.

Comment: Why do I get 401 not authorized in response? Is this CORS issue?

Comment: Probably not related to CORS. What are getting in the response? Check everything. Maybe there's some information available that will tell you what the problem is. Check you console. What do you see? Do you see the real request being made? It's kinda hard to say on my end what the problem is. It could be any number of things. But generally 401 means your not authorized, maybe bad credentials I don't know

Comment: Please see response from request. I just updated by question

Comment: Also added screen shot

Comment: So what I am seeing in the image is just the interaction from the preflight request. If you look at the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, it shows the headers that the server is allowing you to send, which doesn't include `authorization`. That would cause the real request to not go through

Comment: Try removing the auhorization header, and then use `options` instead of `{headers: headers}` because the options sets the `withCredentials`. Maybe the credentials are in the cookies and not supposed to be sent in the authorization header. Can't be really sure as I can't test this type of thing.